# Multiprocessing either never finishes or takes longer than serial processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

For some reason, Example 1's multiprocessing portion prints out a time far greater than the serial portion, and Example 2 just runs forever... I'm wondering if this is an issue with my using VSCode/Jupyter Notebook rather than the code itself, which I got from a couple tutorials I found online.

Example 1:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import math

results_a = []
results_b = []

def calc_one(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        results_a.append(math.sqrt(number **4))

def calc_two(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        results_b.append(math.sqrt(number**5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_list = list(range(20))
    start = time.time()
    calc_one(number_list)
    calc_two(number_list)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time for process one: " + str(end - start))

    start = time.time()
    p1 = mp.Process(target = calc_one, args = (number_list,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target = calc_two, args = (number_list,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    end = time.time()
    print("Time for process two: " + str(end - start))
```

Example 2:

```
def f(n):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(100):
        sum += x*x
    return sum

if __name__ == "__main__":

    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    start = time.time()
    
    result = []
    for n in array:
        result.append(f(n))
    print(result)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time for process one: " + str(end - start))

    start = time.time()
    result = []
    p = Pool()
    result = p.map(f, array)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(result)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time for process one: " + str(end - start))
```

Comment: You aren't doing anywhere near enough work in each process for the time taken to launch the process to be worth it.  Also, in Example 1 you're not waiting for the processes to finish, so your timing isn't meaningful.

Comment: for each process in multiprocessing task that you created, the system has to 1. start a new python interpreter, 2. reinterpret the module and load all the dependencies, 3. open a pipe communication between the two processes, 4. send over the inputs (encoding and decoding them), overall it's not beneficial to create a new process unless the function is taking longer than 1 second to run, and even then, you should reuse your spawned processes instead of creating a new process for each function call.

Comment: example function works only few milliseconds so processes can't run faster. Try ie. `range(200000)` and processes will run faster - but still they need only few seconds. But you should use `p1.join()` `p2.join()` to wait for end of precesses - to get correct time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that ended up working for me was:

```
func(num):
    print(num * num)

import multiprocessing.dummy as mp
p = mp.Pool(5)
list = p.starmap(func, y for y in range(3, 100))
p.close()
p.join()
```

The process I ran contained a function that was quite a bit more intensive than the one shown above as func(), but it still worked. For my function, it took in multiple arguments, so I organized my arguments into a list of tuples.